# how to keep ghost moving logic pacman

Tags: javascript

I'm building a 2D pacman clone (javascript and CSS) and i'm trying to move a ghost/mummy. I've written moveGhostDown/Up/Left/Right. Right now it just makes one step down. I tried wrapping if condition in the moveGhost in the while loop but it crashes the app. How do i keep it moving and don't make instant leaps? I also tried using setTimeout, but it didn't work.

```
function moveGhostDown() {
    if ((grid[ghost.y + 1][ghost.x] !== STONE) && (grid[ghost.y + 1][ghost.x] !== KEY)) {
        let last = grid[ghost.y + 1][ghost.x];
        grid[ghost.y][ghost.x] = last;
        ghost.y = ghost.y + 1;
        grid[ghost.y][ghost.x] = MUMMY;
    }
}
```

```
function moveGhost() { 
    if ((pacman.x > ghost.x) && (pacman.y > ghost.y)) {
        moveGhostDown();
        // moveGhostRight();
        // moveLeft();
    } else if ((pacman.x >= ghost.x) && (pacman.y <= ghost.y)) {
        moveGhosrUp();      
    } else if ((pacman.x < ghost.x) && (pacman.y < ghost.y)) {
        moveGhostRight();
        // moveGhostLeft();
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

moveGhosrUp

Looks like you have a typo

Comment: Thanks, i updated it and it doesn't affect the code. The else if is never triggered